# Got error in getView() in Adapter when i trying to put gridview in fragment i don't know why?

Tags: android

I am trying to show installed app list as a gridview in a fragment.
It seems that the code is ok(maybe). but when I try to test it.
It get an error in `getView()` which is in Adapter class.
what should I do to fix this issue?

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<TeachersModel> datas;
    private boolean isShowDelete;

    public GridAdapter(Context context, List<TeachersModel> datas){
        this.context=context;
        this.datas=datas;
    }
    //返回子项的个数
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (datas.size()+1);
    }
    //返回子项对应的对象
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return datas.get(position);
    }
    //返回子项的下标
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    //返回子项视图
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView==null){
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.model_teachers,null);
            viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.animalImage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv);
            viewHolder.animalName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            viewHolder.deleteImage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_markView);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);//设置tag
        }else{
            view=convertView;
            viewHolder= (ViewHolder) view.getTag();//由tag获取对象
        }

        if(position<datas.size()) {
            Grid_item animal= (Grid_item) getItem(position);
            viewHolder.animalName.setText(animal.getAnimal());
            viewHolder.animalImage.setImageResource(animal.getImgId());
            viewHolder.deleteImage.setVisibility(isShowDelete ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);//根据标识位isShowDelete决定是否显示删除图片按钮
            if (isShowDelete) {
                viewHolder.deleteImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        datas.remove(position);
                        setIsShowDelete(false);
                    }
                });
            }
    }else{
        viewHolder.animalName.setText("点击添加");
        viewHolder.animalImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);
        viewHolder.deleteImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
        return view;
    }
    //创建ViewHolder类
    class ViewHolder{
        ImageView animalImage,deleteImage;
        TextView animalName;
    }
    public void setIsShowDelete(boolean isShowDelete) {
        this.isShowDelete = isShowDelete;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

---

---

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button addTeachers;
    Button modTeachers;

    private ListView listView;
    private GridView gridView;
    private ArrayList<TeachersModel> teachersModelArrayList;
    private CustomAdapterTeacher customAdapterTeacher;
    private DatabaseHelperTeacher databaseHelperTeacher;

   //grid
   private GridAdapter gridAdapter;
    private List<Grid_item> datas = new ArrayList<Grid_item>();
    private boolean isShowDelete;

    public  void addTeachersActivity(){
        addTeachers= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add_teacher);
        addTeachers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent addTeachersr = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddCourseTeachers.class);
                startActivity(addTeachersr);

            }
        });
    }

    public  void modTeachersActivity(){
        modTeachers= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_teacher_modify);
        modTeachers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent modTeachersr = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ModTeacher.class);
                startActivity(modTeachersr);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addTeachersActivity();
        modTeachersActivity();

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.teachers_lv);

        databaseHelperTeacher = new DatabaseHelperTeacher(this);

        teachersModelArrayList = databaseHelperTeacher.getAllTeachers();

        customAdapterTeacher = new CustomAdapterTeacher(this,teachersModelArrayList);
        gridView.setAdapter(customAdapterTeacher);

        databaseHelperTeacher = new DatabaseHelperTeacher(this);

        List<TeachersModel> teachersModelList = databaseHelperTeacher.getAllTeachers();

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.teachers_lv);
        initDatas();
        gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(this, teachersModelList);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == parent.getChildCount() - 1) {
                    addDatas();
                }
            }
        });

        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (position < datas.size()) {
                    if (isShowDelete) {//删除图片显示时长按隐藏
                        isShowDelete = false;
                        gridAdapter.setIsShowDelete(isShowDelete);
                    } else {//删除图片隐藏式长按显示
                        isShowDelete = true;
                        gridAdapter.setIsShowDelete(isShowDelete);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    private void addDatas() {
        Grid_item animalAdd = new Grid_item("個人區域", R.drawable.selfarea);
        datas.add(animalAdd);
        gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void initDatas() {
        Grid_item animal0 = new Grid_item("家", R.drawable.home);
        Grid_item animal1 = new Grid_item("工廠", R.drawable.factory);

        datas.add(animal0);
        datas.add(animal1);

    }   

}


----------
```

---

---

```
package com.sayem.geeknot.sqlitecrud;

public class Grid_item {

    public Grid_item(String animal, int imgId) {
        this.animal = animal;
        this.imgId = imgId;
    }
    private String animal;
    private int imgId;
    public String getAnimal() {
        return animal;
    }
    public void setAnimal(String animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }
    public int getImgId() {
        return imgId;
    }
    public void setImgId(int imgId) {
        this.imgId = imgId;
    }
}
```

---

---

```
----------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.sayem.geeknot.sqlitecrud.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_teacher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_teacher_modify"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mod" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/teachers_lv"
        android:layout_width="381dp"
        android:layout_height="326dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.543"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.942"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


</LinearLayout>


----------
```

---

---

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.sayem.geeknot.sqlitecrud.ModTeacher">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/inst_text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#919191"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/teachers_lvi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/teachers_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textColor="#000"
             android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/name"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/teachers_course"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/course"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/teachers_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/email"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="@string/phone" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/teachers_phone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="#000" />

            </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,UseCompoundDrawables">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:layout_height="55dip"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="70dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/delete_markView"
        android:layout_width="20dip"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/delete"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> Here is the error log

```
 Process: com.sayem.geeknot.sqlitecrud, PID: 11255
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sayem.geeknot.sqlitecrud.TeachersModel cannot be cast to com.sayem.geeknot.sqlitecrud.Grid_item
    at com.sayem.geeknot.sqlitecrud.GridAdapter.getView(GridAdapter.java:56)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
    at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1065)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: which error you get?

Comment: It would be good to use recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager.

Comment: Please look into how to create a [mcve]. There is far too much code here, most of which is not needed to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `getView` & `ViewHolder`code with this:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.model_teachers,parent,false);
            viewHolder=new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);//设置tag
        }else{
            viewHolder= (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();//由tag获取对象
        }
        if(position<datas.size()) {
            Grid_item animal= (Grid_item) getItem(position);
            viewHolder.animalName.setText(animal.getAnimal());
            viewHolder.animalImage.setImageResource(animal.getImgId());
            viewHolder.deleteImage.setVisibility(isShowDelete ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);//根据标识位isShowDelete决定是否显示删除图片按钮
            if (isShowDelete) {
                viewHolder.deleteImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        datas.remove(position);
                        setIsShowDelete(false);
                    }
                });
            }
    }else{
        viewHolder.animalName.setText("点击添加");
        viewHolder.animalImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);
        viewHolder.deleteImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
        return convertView;
    }
    //创建ViewHolder类
    class ViewHolder{
        ImageView animalImage,deleteImage;
        TextView animalName;

        public ViewHolder(View view)
        {
            view.animalImage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv);
            view.animalName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            view.deleteImage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_markView);
        }
    }
```

You need to find views in `ViewHolder` constructor and i have also done some optimization.

**Update**
Look the problem is you are sending `teachersModelList` to `GridAdapter` which is List type and inside `getView` you are typecasting   to Grid_item change this:

```
Grid_item animal= (Grid_item) getItem(position);
```

to :

```
TeachersModel animal= (TeachersModel) getItem(position);
```

Comment: public ViewHolder(View view)
        {
            view.animalImage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv);
            view.animalName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            view.deleteImage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_markView);
        }     (((get error Translation can't pass)

Comment: He got worse worse

Comment: viewHolder.animalName.setText(animal.getAnimal());
                viewHolder.animalImage.setImageResource(animal.getImgId());    
getAnimal()   and   getImgId() error
 view.animalImage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv);
                view.animalName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
                view.deleteImage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_markView);
animalImage,animalName,deleteImage also error

Comment: what do you want to show in GridView, teachers list? or Grid_item list?

Comment: I want the animal and animalName to Transfer to  model_teachers.xml 
and let model_teachers.xml delete_markView can use Others don't show up